Is there a way to specify bottom lines columns alignment as default in beamer
In documentation, I found that I can specify top lines alignment as default by class option t. I tried the same for b, but it doesn't work.

Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a document environment.

You could redefine the columns environment to use b as default:
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment<>{columns}[1][]{%
  \begin{actionenv}#2%
  \ifbeamer@onlytextwidth
    \def\beamer@colentrycode{\hbox to\textwidth\bgroup\ignorespaces}%
    \def\beamer@colexitcode{\unskip\egroup}
  \else%
    \def\beamer@colentrycode{%
      \hbox to\textwidth\bgroup%
      \leavevmode%
      \hskip-\beamer@leftmargin%
      \nobreak%
      \beamer@tempdim=\textwidth%
      \advance\beamer@tempdim by\beamer@leftmargin%
      \advance\beamer@tempdim by\beamer@rightmargin%
      \hbox to\beamer@tempdim\bgroup%
      \hbox{}\hfill\ignorespaces}%
    \def\beamer@colexitcode{\egroup%
      \nobreak%
      \hskip-\beamer@rightmargin\egroup}%
  \fi%
  \setkeys{beamer@col}{b}%
  \setkeys{beamer@col}{#1}%
  \par%
  \beamer@colentrycode%
  \def\beamer@colclose{}\ignorespaces}%
  {\beamer@colclose\def\beamer@colclose{}\beamer@colexitcode\end{actionenv}}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}
  \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
  content...
  \end{column}
  \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
  content...
  
  test
  
   test
   
    test
    
     test
     
      test
  \end{column}  
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}

